# Hover expand issue on webpage

Tags: html, css, hover

I have this code for my website where the blocks are supposed to expand into the middle, but when i hover over the blocks on the right side it will also drag the other blocks with it into the middle. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Website</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        .column {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .block {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 100px;
            transition: all 0.5s;
            background-color: lightgreen;
        }
        .block:hover {
            width: 150px;
        }
        .left .block:hover {
            margin-right: 50px;
        }
        .right .block:hover {
            margin-left: 50px;
        }
        .background {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background">
        <!-- background -->
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column left">
            <div class="block">Block 1</div>
            <div class="block">Block 2</div>
            <div class="block">Block 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column right">
            <div class="block">Block 4</div>
            <div class="block">Block 5</div>
            <div class="block">Block 6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Already asked ChatGPT but it wasnt able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a `.block` element wider on hover, also increases the width of the container you put those blocks in. And since your blocks are left-aligned in both of those containers, the un-hovered ones in the right then appear to also "move."

You need to align the blocks in the right container, *to* the right:

```
.column.right {
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```